# Python, импорт нескольких классов модуля из функции

Tags: python, классы, python-import

У меня есть скрипт 1:

```
import sys


class Test:
    def print_method(self):
        TestClass1().myclassfunc()


def myfunc(path_to_module):
    sys.path.append(path_to_module)
    from mymodule import TestClass1, TestClass2, TestClass3, ..., TestClass15, TestClass16

    a = Test()
    a.print_method()


myfunc(r'D:\Programming\CALCULATIONS\sandbox')
```

В этом скрипте я хочу импортировать все классы из модуля, который импортируется через sys внутри функции `myfunc`. Модуль выглядит так:

```
class TestClass1:
    def myclassfunc(self):
        return 'TestClass method'


class TestClass2:
    ...

class TestClass3:
    ...

...<и еще много классов, которые нужны>..


class TestClass15:
    ...


class TestClass16:
    ...
```

При вызове функции `myfunc` ловлю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>", line 26, in <module>
    myfunc()
  File "<path>", line 23, in myfunc
    a.print_method()
  File "<path>", line 15, in print_method
    TestClass1().myclassfunc()
NameError: global name 'TestClass1' is not defined
```

Comment: Описание ошибки `name 'TestClass' is not defined` не соответствует коду `TestClass1().myclassfunc()`

Comment: @АлексейР правил код и забыл обновить, обновил

Comment: Как вариант, собирайте классы в список, передавайте их  объект Test, внутри делайте что-то типа `test_classes[0]().myclassfunc()`. Если нужно чтобы классы были доступны на глобальном уровне, то возможно имеет смысл просто импорт вынести на верхний уровень.

Comment: Либо, если один конкретный класс нужен в Test, передавайте этот конкретный класс. Это в целом похоже на попытку реализации Dependency Injection.

Comment: import внутри функции, добавляет имена в контекст локальных переменных функции, а для использования в другой функции, нужно добавлять в пространство имен модуля.